# Expression must have integral or enum type

Tags: c++, visual-c++

OK, so I'm trying to do a simple program that reads 2 input files (names & grades), then displays and prints them to an output file. So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void ReadNames();
void ReadGrades();

void ReadNames()
{
char names [15][5];

ifstream myfile("names.txt");

if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            myfile.get(names[i],15,'\0');
            cout << names[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
else cout << "Error loadng file!" << endl;
}

void ReadGrades()
{
char grades [15][5];

ifstream myfile2("grades.txt");

if(myfile2.is_open())
{
    while(!myfile2.eof())
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++)
        {
            myfile2.get(grades[k],15,'\0');
            cout << grades[k];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
else cout << "Error loadng file!" << endl;
}

int main()
{

char Name [10];
int  grade [10][10];

ReadNames();
ReadGrades();

for (int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << Name[i];
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    grade [i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile Visual Studio is giving me two errors:

> illegal, right operand has type 'const char [1]'
>
> > operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect

I know it's something simple but I have no idea what the problem is. The error seems to stem from the `grade [i][j] << " ";`  line. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are telling you you need somehting like

```
std::cout << grade [i][j] << " ";
```

`grade [i][j]` is a `char`, `" "` is a `const char[1]`, and there is no `operator<<` that operates on such a RHS and LHS combination.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to output the value of `grade[i][j]` but you are not using `std::cout`. Try like this:

```
std::cout << grade [i][j] << " ";
```

The `<<` is the [left shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Since it is not defined for char (such as `grade[i][j]`), you get the error.